# Completely Remove an Exchange Cluster even though it's cluster info is long gone?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2003, cluster, windows-cluster

With the proviso that I realize I screwed the pooch on this, here's my situation.

We used to have an Exchange 2003 two-node cluster.  Several years back we migrated to Google Apps.  When we did that, I shutdown the clusters, decommisioned the servers, and destroyed the shared storage.  All backups are long gone at this point.  ***What I didn't do***, was properly remove either the cluster or the exchange server from AD.

Fast forward to now, for reasons that I will not go into, we're moving back to Exchange.  I need to uninstall exchange 2003 and the cluster so we can install the new one.

All I have been able to get back is node of the exchange cluster.  That's it...  no shared storage, no partner node.  I *might* be able to revive the other node, but that's iffy.  I'm not sure it would help anyway.

So my question is...  is there any way that I can remove exchange/this cluster from my domain, or am I fucked?

Please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

The following article explains how to manually remove Exchange. ADSI edit is your friend.

Specifically look under "Remove the Exchange Server 2003 server from Active Directory"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/833396

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing this and the other guy's solution in the next day or two.  I'll report back whether it worked and if I find anything useful to put down on top of this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to clean the old Exchange config from Active Directory.  I found this [article](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/remove-exchange-server-entire-exchange-organization.html).  Note - this is not for the faint of heart as it requires liberal use of ADSIEdit.  Be careful and ensure AD is backed up BEFORE you start and KNOW your AD recovery password.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be testing this and the other guy's solution in the next day or two.  I'll report back whether it worked and if I find anything useful to put down on top of this.